# mail id verification using python

Tags: python

Here is the code, which i have used for mail id verification with python:

```
import re

with open("mail.txt","r") as k:
    `enter code here`arr=k.readlines()
arr1=[]
#print (arr)
for line in arr:
    arr1.extend(re.split("\s+|,+|:+|;+",line,re.M|re.I))

print (arr1)    

for j in arr1:
    if (re.match("(.+)\@(.)+",j,re.M|re.I)):
        print (j)
```

But, my problem is that `nj@hotmail.comhhhh` gets printed. I want only the mail ids with 3 letter domain names to be printed.

Comment: please, edit your question

Comment: So, what is you question?

Comment: Question is  "nj@hotmail.comhhhh should not be printed".I want only the mail ids with domain in,com,net,i.e 3 characters domain names should be allowed.

Comment: @bibhu I edited it to include your actual question.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution is to make a tld list ( or you can download one ) , and use it to validate your emails .
Tld list example :

```
tld_list = [ 'com', 'net', 'org', 'gov', 'edu', 'it', 'es', 'fr' ]
```

Now use it in your loop :

```
for j in arr1:
    if re.match("(.+)\@(.)+",j,re.M|re.I) and j.split('.')[-1].lower() in tld_list :
        print(j)
```

Comment: He said 3 letter domain names

Comment: @Noah Cristino this is just an example, the OP could modify the `tld_list`  to fit his needs

Comment: Good point, he should do it the way you say in your answer, because that makes it better at validation, since if it was just all 3 letter domain names someone could do something that doesn't exist, and es, fr etc. would be invalid.

Comment: j.split('.')[-1].lower() in tld_list :Could you please explain me this part of code ??The code is working fine.

Comment: ok, `j.split('.')` splits `j` to a list , `[-1]` selects the last item of that list , `lower()` turns it to lower case .  Example : `"nj@hotmail.Com".split('.')[-1].lower()` returns 'com'